# Can you change the element in the list while reversing in Python?

Tags: python, list

For example I have a list x

```
x = ['(A)','(B)','(C)']
```

If we reversed() it, it will look like this.

```
x = ['(C)','(B)','(A)']
```

Now, I want to change the parenthesis () into a hash #.

The output that im looking

```
x = ['#C#','#B#','#A#']
```

Can I do that in python??

Comment: Certainly you can. Did you try to write code for it? Was there something unsatisfactory about your code?

Comment: Yes, you can. Use a list comprehension to transform the list elements. The fact that you're reversing is irrelevant.

Comment: How would you do it if you weren't reversing?

Comment: Hint: use the `str.replace()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import re

x = ['(A)','(B)','(C)']
x = [re.sub(r"\((\w)\)", r"#\1#", item) for item in reversed(x)]

print(x)
>>>['#C#', '#B#', '#A#']
```

Comment: Just in case regex is not for everyone, an alternative is simply `[item.replace("(", "#").replace(")", "#") for item in reversed(x)]`